# What does '_IO(...)' mean in C headers in Linux?

Tags: c, header-files, c-preprocessor

I have a Linux standard header file e.g.

```
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-35/include/linux/usbdevice_fs.h
```

which contain `define` statements as follows:

```
#define USBDEVFS_SUBMITURB32       _IOR('U', 10, struct usbdevfs_urb32)
#define USBDEVFS_DISCARDURB        _IO('U', 11)
#define USBDEVFS_REAPURB           _IOW('U', 12, void *)
```

What does '_IOR', '_IO' and '_IOW' mean? What value is actually given e.g. to `USBDEVFS_DISCARDURB`?

Comment: See also duplicate question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22496123/what-is-the-meaning-of-this-macro-iormy-macig-0-int/40465177#40465177

Answer (score 9, accepted):

They define ioctl numbers, based on ioctl function and input parameters. 
The are defined in kernel, in `include/asm-generic/ioctl.h`.

You need to include `<linux/ioctl.h>` (or `linux/asm-generic/ioctl.h`) in your program. Before including
`/usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-35/include/linux/usbdevice_fs.h`

You can't "precompile" this values (e.g. `USBDEVFS_DISCARDURB`), because they can be different on other platforms. For example, you are developing your code on plain old x86, but then someone will try to use it on x86_64/arm/mips/etc. So you should always include kernel's `ioctl.h` to make sure, you are using right values.

Comment: Now we are getting close. Including this particular header file I was able to compute the numerical value of the `_IO` construct.

Comment: @Alex, but be beware, that numerical value possibly can be changed in next kernel version (e.g. sizeof struct usbdevfs_urb32 will be changed). You'd better always include this two files and use defined name.

Comment: The IOCTLs are supposed to stay stable from version to version because they represent a user ABI.  Old binaries must work on new kernels.  However the IOCTL values differ on various platforms and that is why one should use the values from the headers: to stay portable across many platforms.

Comment: @goertzenator, yes, you are right in general. I was speaking as embedded developer. There are lots of strange things can happen during active development. I have seen how IOCTL values changed on the same kernel version, but yes, it was rather exceptional case. I'll update the answer.

Answer (score 1):

These are also macros defined elsewhere.

In general if you want to see your code after pre-processor has been computed use

```
gcc -E foo.c
```

this will output your code pre-processed

For example:

foo.c

```
#define FORTY_TWO 42

int main(void)
{
  int foo = FORTY_TWO;
}
```

will give you with `gcc -E foo.c`:

```
int main(void)
{
  int foo = 42;
}
```

Comment: I cannot see the variable `USBDEVFS_DISCARDURB` in the output of `gcc -E /usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-35/include/linux/usbdevice_fs.h` anymore. How can I see the actual value? Or how can I find out where those macros are defined?

Comment: If you want to also see the macro definitions and the `#include` statements, add the `-dDI` flag. To prevent macro expansion, make it `-dDNI`

Comment: @Alex See my edit; you wouldn't see the macro USBDEVFS_DISCARDURB because `gcc -E` has preprocessed it and replaced it in-place by its value. `gcc -E` is also not supposed to be used on a header file but on a source file as stated in my answer.

Comment: @Eregrith: I understand what `gcc -E` is doing, but it does not answer my question. I still need to find out the value of the variable `USBDEVFS_DISCARDURB` for example, or to find the definition of the `_IO` command (to derive the value myself).

Comment: Daft question but can't you just add a `USBDEVFS_DISCARDURB` to your source file then preprocess it?  Your change doesn't have to compile; you can delete it as soon as you've seen the preprocessor output.

Comment: @simonc: Your suggestion worked, but did not answer my question. It turned out that `USBDEVFS_DISCARDURB=_IO('U', 20)`! But what IS `_IO('U', 20)`? I am expecting an int value.

Comment: Then it proves that `_IO('U', 20)` is not a macro but indeed a function

Comment: @Eregrith: Interesting subtlety, but it still does not answer my  question. I need a numerical value (an int) that this variable stands for.

Comment: If you expect an `int` and just need its value why not simply `printf("%i\n", _IO('U', 20));`?

Comment: @Eregrith: Because I have to compile the code. I get a lot of errors, and it is just a header. But I guess I have no choice to write some c code which imports the header code and try to sort out all of the errors...